# pages with .php extension redirect to .html

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I m trying to redirect all pages with extension .php to .html
with the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /rules/$1.html [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.html$ /rules/$1.php [NC,L]
```

but got an error "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Comment: You are rewriting `.php` to `.html`. Also you are rewriting `.html` to `.php`. How do you figure this is going to work.

Comment: Why have you added the fourth line? Seems like that is causing the loop.

Comment: you have php pages(like abc.php)and you want to run these pages as abc.html. Is this is ur requirement?

Comment: @AmitGarg , Yes exactly i want all of my php pages to open with .html extension. 
like abc.php as abc.html

Comment: @AmitGarg when i use this: RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.html$ /rules/$1.php [NC,L]

all of my pages are open with .html extension and opens with .php extension too :(, this is actually the problem

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos , when i did not added the fourth line the browser shows the error "Not Found"

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos

when i use this: RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.html$ /rules/$1.php [NC,L]

all of my pages are open with .html extension but open with .php extension too :(, this is actually the problem.

Comment: What do you mean that your pages are open with .html extension but open with .php extension too? like youpage.html.php ?

Comment: @PeeHaa

when i use this: RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.html$ /rules/$1.php [NC,L] all of my pages are open with .html extension but open with .php extension too :(, this is actually the problem. i want to open these pages only with .html extension

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos i mean to say abc.php and abc.html both are opening with this rule (  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.html$ /rules/$1.php [NC,L]  ). i just want to open my pages with .html extension

Answer (score 0):

You have done first redirection of .php to .html and after that you doing .html to .php redirect so, that will recursion of redirection.

make code like this. that will redirect .php to .html files.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /rules/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply,
But the problem is, the actual pages are with .php extension in the directory, 
if i redirect these to .html browser gives me the error "Not Found"
thats y i m using the second rule to open .php files with .html extension

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.html? [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```